# Compare the inputs and get the response?

Tags: mule, dataweave

**Input 01**:

```
{
    "labelItems": [{
        "label": "manager",
        "role": "MA"
    }, {
        "label": "Developer",
        "role": "DEV"
    }]
 }
```

**Input 02:**

```
{
    "List": [{
            "id": "M123",
            "label": "Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": "L240",
            "label": "Lead"
        },
        {
            "id": "D250",
            "label": "Developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Final output:

```
{
    "Labels": [{
            "id": "M123",
            "role": "MA"
        },
        {
            "id": "D250",
            "role": "DEV"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone provide me the above desired final output response, we have two input payloads and compare two payloads with the label field and get the id & role fields from the array of the list.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to iterate on Input 02 ( I have set Input 01 as the payload to this script) and pass over the label to filter the payload, to procure the corresponding role. Have used `capitalize` since the `manager` in payload (Input 01) starts with lowercase `m` while the same starts with Uppercase `m` in Input 02 label for `id` M123.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
var inp2 = {
    "List": [{
            "id": "M123",
            "label": "Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": "L240",
            "label": "Lead"
        },
        {
            "id": "D250",
            "label": "Developer"
        }
    ]
}
---
Labels: inp2.List map ((item, index) -> {
    id: item.id,
    role: (payload.labelItems filter (capitalize($.label) == item.label )).'role'[0]

}) filter (!($.role == null))
```

Another modification to this could be:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
var inp2 = {
    "List": [{
            "id": "M123",
            "label": "Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": "L240",
            "label": "Lead"
        },
        {
            "id": "D250",
            "label": "Developer"
        }
    ]
}
var interim = payload.labelItems map {
    (capitalize($.label)): $.role
}
---
Labels: inp2.List map ((item, index) -> {
    id: item.id,
    role: interim[(item.label)][0]

}) filter (!($.role == null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by using joins. I have used [leftJoin](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-leftjoin) for joining the arrays.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var inp2 = {
    "List": [{
            "id": "M123",
            "label": "Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": "L240",
            "label": "Lead"
        },
        {
            "id": "D250",
            "label": "Developer"
        }
    ]
}

---
Labels: leftJoin (payload.labelItems, inp2.List, 
            (labelItems)-> lower(labelItems.label), (listItems) -> lower(listItems.label)) 
        map {
            id: $.r.id,
            role: $.l.role
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over input 1 and compare the current item's label with label in in2's list to get the corresponding id

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var in1={
    "labelItems": [{
        "label": "manager",
        "role": "MA"
    }, {
        "label": "Developer",
        "role": "DEV"
    }]
 }
var in2={
    "List": [{
            "id": "M123",
            "label": "Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": "L240",
            "label": "Lead"
        },
        {
            "id": "D250",
            "label": "Developer"
        }
    ]
}
---
Labels: in1.labelItems default [] map (item, index) -> {
    id: in2.List[?(lower($.label) == lower(item.label))][0].id,
    role: item.role
}
```

Have used `lower` to avoid any case sensitivity